# What is rapidjson's equivalent to libjson JSONNode?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am trying to replace JSONNode with the libjson equivalent.  I think Value is the equivalent in rapidjson, but I'm not sure.

I saw this link [rapidjson](https://codeflu.blog/2015/02/26/understanding-rapidjson/), which seems to indicate to use Value for a node in rapidjson, but I wanted to check.

The DOM has to have nodes, but I would expect it to be called Node, not Value, if I want the equivalent of this libjson use (JSONNode is libjson):

```
   template<typename T>
            OurNode(const String &n, const T &v)
            :   // class member initializations
            pNodeLibJson(new JSONNode(n, v)),
            index(0)
            {}
```

So if I want to use a rapidJson node (and it must have a node if it has DOM), would it be this?

```
  template<typename T>
            OurNode(const String &n, const T &v)
            :   // class member initializations
            pNodeRapidJson(new Value(n, v)),
            index(0)
            {}
```

Comment: You'd better show us code you have because its unclear where you want replace JSONNode and what you want to get.

Comment: @user2807083 - see above code added.

Comment: Any idea @MiloYip ?